# How to find a specific match in nested Python dictionaries?

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, dictionary, iteration

I try to find a match deep in nested Python dictionaries. I am looking for a specific **nickname** to find its **player_id**. I have the nickname that I look for stored in **name** (name = "zero10").

I am trying to find a match by "if name in value:".

To rephrase my question: How to retrieve dictionary that has one of its values matching to my search?

```
json_file = r.text
dct = json.loads(json_file)
for key, value in dct.iteritems():
    if "data" in key:
        for minilist in value:
            for key, value in minilist.iteritems():
                if name in value:
```

My data is below (I succesfully transform it through json module):

```
{"status":"ok","count":3,"data":
[
{"nickname":"zero10","account_id":500749494}, 
{"nickname":"Zero100","account_id":505683972},
{"nickname":"zero100v1","account_id":502108240}
]}
```

I prefer to have end result that would look like

```
{"nickname":"zero10","account_id":500749494}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code, not 100% sure if I understood the question, but here it is:

**Code:**

```
name = "zero10"

d1 = {"status":"ok", "count":3, "data":
[{"nickname":"zero10", "account_id":500749494},
{"nickname":"Zero100", "account_id":505683972},
{"nickname":"zero100v1", "account_id":502108240}
]}

result = None
for key, value in d1.iteritems():
    if "data" == key:
        for dic2 in value:
            if dic2['nickname'] == name:
                result = dic2['account_id']

print result
```

**Output:**

```
>>> 500749494
```

If you want to get the dictionary, change `result = dic2['account_id']` with `result = dic2`

**Output:**

```
>>> {'nickname': 'zero10', 'account_id': 500749494}
```

**Notes:**
This will only work if in the pairs of the dictionary of the "data" value in `d1` are of the form: `{"nickname" : "...", "account_id" : ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
name = 'zero10'
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    if "data" in key:
        for minilist in value:
            #print minilist
            if minilist['nickname'] == name:
                print minilist
```

Result is this:

```
{'nickname': 'zero10', 'account_id': 500749494}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making your life harder than it needs to be. I'd break up the code, separating the response validation from finding a player. That makes it easier to understand (for my brain at least ;) ). The function `dict.get(key, default)` avoids the explicit `data` check.

```
def find_player(wanted_nick, data):
    for player in data:
        if player["nickname"] == wanted_nick:
            return player
    return None

print(find_player("zero10", dct.get("data", [])))
```

Output:

```
{'nickname': 'zero10', 'account_id': 500749494}
```

Also note that `"data" in key` is dangerous, because you're doing a *contained* check. It would also evaluate the true, if your response dict would contain a key that *includes* the word "data", i.e. when it looks like so: `{"no_data_found":True}. Not what you want.